# how to add custom package name to software selection menu and download them

Tags: boot, 16.04, software-center, startup

I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu 16.04 lts and I want to display the software selection during installation like this

[image: img_selection]

Like I want to display download KVM and docker in the list and select it and download them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's tasksel. Download it's source and hack at it.